# Recyclerview child item on click issues

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I have a Reyclerview in a grid setting.

this is how it looks

[image]

My problem is
i have implemented the onTouchListeners of both the red button in my recyclerview child card and also the whole card's on Touch.

[Listening to onTouch events of the red button in my adapter
and the OnItemTouchListener of the recyclerview entire child in my fragment]

Now when i click on the red button
both the click listeners fire

How do i make sure that when i click on the red button only that onTouchListener is fired and not the entire cards onItemTouch listener?

In the normal gridview
the onclick listeners were not overlapping when i clicked on the red one only onclick2 fired and when i clicked on the whole card onclick1 fired

Thanks for any pointers or help with this regard

Code snippet:

```
mRecyclerApps.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        startActivity(context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(installedApps.get(position).getPackageName() ));
                    }
                })
        );
```

**Red area onTouchListener in adapter**

```
 holder._appInfo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Toast.makeText(_ctx, "info button Clicked for " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**Using onClickListener doesnt help too,gives same output**

```
holder._appInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(_ctx, "info button Clicked for " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done it wrong, 
you can not add **itemtouchlistener** along with inside child touch,
All you need to do is make that view touch, and child touch

```
//parent touch event
holder.main_view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            // parent touch login
            return false;
        }
    });
//child touch event
holder._appInfo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Toast.makeText(_ctx, "info button Clicked for " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: replace holder with parent view.
for example - appInfo is a child of main_view then
holder.main_view.setOnTouchListener